# Нет, что вы (./!/,/-)...

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким знаком препинания отделяются слова "нет, что вы" от слов опровержения ожиданий или предположений собеседника: знаком конца предложения (в данном случае возможна точка либо восклицательный знак), запятой или тире? Например: "Это поэма?" - "Нет, что вы (./!/,/-) Л/либретто".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы так написала: Нет, что вы - либретто! Знак тире будет обозначать все пропущенные слова  и интонации, которые ваш собеседник домыслит сам.

Comment: Из Вашего варианта следует: "Нет, что Вы - (какое) либретто?" (это зависит от тональности слов, которые я произношу: так или этак. Я могу произнести таким тоном, что будете правы Вы, а могу, напротив, убедить Вас, что прав я)

Comment: Здесь возможны два варианта диалога:
1) Это либретто? - Нет, что вы - ПОЭМА!
2) Это поэма? - Нет, ЧТО ВЫ - поэма! Либретто!
На выделенных словах делается логическое ударение (повышение тона и усиление голоса). Таким образом, мы имеем сходное пунктуационное  оформление двух фраз. А их разное содержание устанавливается в контексте и с помощью различной интонации.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется наиболее удачным вариант "Нет, что вы - либретто!". Не исключено, что возможны другие схемы пунктуационного оформления, варьирующиеся в зависимости от смыслового содержания, но тире лучше всего передает смысловые оттенки, которые я в эту фразу вкладываю.

Answer (score 1):

"Нет, что Вы (пропущено слово: "говорите")? (При подчёркнутой экспрессии после вопросительного знака: ! или !!) Это либретто (При подчёркнутой экспрессии: ! или !!)" Уже наличие слова "что" предполагает постановку в конце предложения  знака "?"

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что *опровержение* лучше выразить отдельной фразой. "Нет, что вы! Это — либретто".